# How to echo incorrectly stored line breaks correctly?

Tags: php, mysql

In my website users can be registered through this page

```
https://www.onlanka.com/friends/add.php?l=default
```

After someone entered their details into "Description" area, I can see line breaks were stored as `&lt;br&gt;` inside the MySQL table.

Then it's output shows `<br>` in the following page (See About row):

```
https://www.onlanka.com/friends/view.php?l=default&id=35201
```

But I need only the line break (break the line / new line) instead of showing `<br>`

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
strip_tags($your_string)
```

to remove unexpected html tags before you save the record into the database.

or if you want to change the html entity into new line br tag

you can use

```
str_replace('&lt;br&gt;', "<br>", $your_string)
```

Comment: Database has &lt;br&gt;  How can I set to store <br>?

Comment: str_replace('&lt;br&gt;', '<br>', $your_string)